# Spring Boot 3.0 upgrade issue, cannot invoke GenericConversionService.addConverter(Converter) because "cs" is null

Tags: spring-boot

I'm upgrade the spring boot to 3.0.0-M4 and I have this test case which works fine in Spring 2.7 but not in 3.0.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
    classes = {
        PubSubBindingsTestConfiguration.class,
        BinderFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        PubSubBinderConfiguration.class,
        PubSubExtendedBindingProperties.class,
        BindingServiceConfiguration.class
    },
    properties = {
      "logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=DEBUG",
      "spring.cloud.stream.pollable-source=customIn",
      "spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.bindings.input.consumer.ack-mode=AUTO_ACK",
      "spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.bindings.input.consumer.auto-create-resources=true",
      "spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.auto-create-resources=false"
    })
class PubSubExtendedBindingsPropertiesTests {

  @Autowired private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  @Test
  void testExtendedPropertiesOverrideDefaults() {
    BinderFactory binderFactory = this.context.getBeanFactory().getBean(BinderFactory.class);
  }
}
```

The test case failed with the following stacktrace:

```
21:11:36.182 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverterConfigurer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryAutoConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'messageConverterConfigurer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.stream-org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceProperties': Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter)" because "cs" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
```